# How to make the dimensions agree in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, error-handling

I am just starting to learn Matlab, and I would be very grateful if someone could clarify my confusion...

I am trying to solve a non-uniform transport equation using the Lax-Wendroff scheme, with the code below. Matlab tells me that there are errors in the last line of the code (U(j+1,2:N)=(1/2).*sigma...), that is, 1. Error using *; 2. Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

I know the dimensions of sigma and U's are not compatible (as matrices), but I have no idea (and experience) on how to fix this... There's no problem with the formula, but I really find it hard to deal with the code.

```
    a = -10;
    b = 10;
    delta_x = (b-a)/N;
    x = a:delta_x:b;

    tfinal = 2;
    delta_t = tfinal/M;
    t = 0:delta_t:tfinal;

    c = 3-2.* exp(-(1/4).*(x.^2)) ;

    sigma = c.*(delta_t/delta_x);

    U=zeros(M+1,N+1);
    U(1,:)=f(x);

    for j=1:M
    U(j+1,2:N)=(1/2).*sigma.*(sigma-1).*U(j,3:N+1)-((sigma).^2-1).*U(j,2:N)+(1/2).*sigma.*(sigma+1)*U(j,1:N-1);
    end
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I have added the size of each variable as a comment and formatted the code a bit. It is still the same code as you posted.

```
a = -10;
b = 10;
delta_x = (b-a)/N;
x = a:delta_x:b;                   % x: 1 x ( N + 1 )

tfinal = 2;
delta_t = tfinal/M;
t = 0:delta_t:tfinal;              % t: 1 x ( M + 1 )

c = 3-2.* exp(-(1/4).*(x.^2)) ;    % c: 1 x ( N + 1 )

sigma = c.*(delta_t/delta_x);      % sigma: 1 x ( N + 1 )

U=zeros(M+1,N+1);                  % U: ( M + 1 ) x ( N + 1 )
U(1,:)=f(x);                       % Assuming f(x): 1 x ( N + 1 ), otherwise you will get an error here.

for j=1:M
    U(j+1,2:N) = (1/2).*sigma.*(sigma-1).*U(j,3:N+1) ...
                -((sigma.^2)-1).*U(j,2:N) ...
                +(1/2).*sigma.*(sigma+1)*U(j,1:N-1);
end
```

You will notice that in first line of `for`-loop you are multiplying `sigma` (of size `1 x ( N + 1 )`)  with `U(j, 3:N+1)` (size: `1 x (N - 1)`). This will not work.
You do the same thing for next two lines of `for`-loop, where the size of `U(j,...)` is not same as size of `sigma`.

I do not know what the actual equation looks like, so can not say for sure how you need to correct for the size mismatch. But you can try replacing `sigma` by say `sigma(3:N+1)` or something equivalent to get the right size.